# How do you maintain objects and variables in memory in javascript/Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Trying to create objects and variables that will be maintained in memory in javascript.  Javascript has a whole bunch of ways to declare things, and different contexts.  How can they be declared so that they will be maintained in memory?

The challenge that I'm having is that this js code (see below for example) is running within a Meteor project.  This means that when other aspects of the project decide to, they appear to re-load/re-initialize this javascript code along with a corresponding HTML template.  I can't figure out how to store something that will still be there when I want it to be.  I've put in a bunch of example variables with different options below to illustrate different possible approaches.  I need to set a variable and be sure that it's still going to be set at a later time (and also be able to test whether it has already been set or not).

Thanks

```
var example = 1;
example2 = 1;
Levels = {
  example3: 0,
  currentNumber: {}, // number of the current level
  available: {}, // which levels are available for use, not greyed-out
  initialized: {}, // have the levels been initialize?
  init: function() {
    if (typeof Levels.initialized !== 'undefined') {
      var example4 = 1;
      example5 = 1;
      Levels.initialized = true;
      Levels.currentNumber = 1;

    }
  },...
```

Comment: What is this code used for? Is it template specific, or should it be set once and available for the session?

Comment: Ideally, set once and available for the session (though template-specific would also be interesting to know).  Thanks

Comment: This is a really board question so it's tricky to give a specific answer. If you want to know how to scope reactive variables to a template, I'd recommend reading [this](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something along the lines of memcache or appcache is what you will need. Check out this package: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/appcache

You can store the variables in a JSON format and cache it in the client browser layer (make sure you keep the data nice and lean)